# I need a help on handling javascript variable inside Jsx code

Tags: reactjs, react-router

ListAllPost.js code --------------------------------

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';

const APIKEY = "loc";
let URL;

class ListAllPost extends Component{

 constructor(props){
   super(props);
   this.state = {
     allPostData : []
   }
 }
 componentWillMount(){
   URL = `http://reduxblog.herokuapp.com/api/posts?${APIKEY}`;
    axios.get(URL).then((resp)=>{
      this.setState({
        allPostData : resp.data
      });
    });
 }

 onClickDelete(e,postId){
   console.log(postId); // undefined // i am expecting the value of id here .

   URL = `http://reduxblog.herokuapp.com/api/posts/${postId}?${APIKEY}`;
   axios.delete(URL).then((resp)=>{
     console.log("deleted"+resp.status)
   });
 }


  render(){
    if(!this.state.allPostData){
      return <div>Loading...</div>
    }

    let listItem = this.state.allPostData.map((post)=>{
      let postId = post.id;
      return(
          <li key = {postId}>
              <Link to = {{pathname : `/viewPost/${postId}`}} >
                {post.title}
              </Link>
              <i onClick = {(postId)=>this.onClickDelete(postId)}>Delete</i>

          </li>
      );
    });
    return(<div>
                <ul>
                  {listItem}
                </ul>
          </div>
        );
  }
}

export default ListAllPost;
```

In the above code inside render function ....
where i am generating a list item that has two child elements like (Link ) tag and  *tag .I need to implement a feature like when i click the  tag i need to redirect whereas when i click the delete () tag the list item has to be deleted .Here in the onClick function when i try to pass postId as a parameter to onClickDelete function it is not passing as i expected ..i know that we have already used a curly braces to call the eventHandlerfunction ...i also tried calling like  Delete*...this is also not working ..Is it right approach in the first place to implement this feature ....?Pls help me out .I m just learning react with some demo project ..any help on this will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly with `Link` you can do

```
<Link to={`/viewPost/${postId}`}>{post.title}</Link>
```

You can read documentation about `Link` [here.](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Link)

With the `onClick` event. You should do:

```
...
onClickDelete = (postId) => {
  // Axios logic here.

  // You should call some kind of state-change inside of the component, 
  // so the component knows that it has to be updated. Like deleting this post
  // from this.state.allPostData.  
}
...

render() {
   ...
     <i onClick={() => this.onClickDelete(postId)}>Delete</i>
   ...
}
```

If you directly pass a function like you did with the onClick event, you only pass the `e` parameter which is the event function that the onChange *always* gives when performing an `onClick` event.

Comment: Thanks for the Quick response .your answer is  infomative and It solved my issue .

Comment: @Madhan.G You're welcome! If this concludes your post, you can accept my answer. Also - Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: one quick question ,<i onClick={() => this.onClickDelete(postId)}>Delete</i> here we are using fat arrow function to pass postId as argument . what is the exact difference between passing it like this <i onClick={(postId) => this.onClickDelete(postId)}>Delete</i> and  this <i onClick={() => this.onClickDelete(postId)}>Delete</i> . though the expected value of postId vary in each case .

Comment: That's because the `<i>` element has no knowledge about the postId that has to be passed to the `onClickDelete` function. 
A HTML element such as `i`, `div`, `span` natively returns the event as an argument to the function. So if you do `<i onClick={(postId) => this.onClickDelete(postId)}>`, the variable `postId` is an event instead. 

If you do want to use the `event` variable. You could do `onClick={(event) => this.onClickDelete(event, postId)}`. The `onClickDelete` function should have (event, postId) as parameters then. You could do this for `event.preventDefault()` for example.

Comment: awesome ..I have accepted the answer but i cant upvote your answer since i am a newbie to stackOverflow...Thank you so much